# Http PUT changes on backend using Angular UI-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am new to angularJS I am using Angular UI -grid editable feature and able to edit it on UI side but edited value is not going to backend/API.

Please see the plunker below. I am able to edit and recommend to send the editable data using ui-grid to API's

[plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/VdmvcOptoP5LC5VSyY9L?p=preview)

Code where I think I need to implement the changes to send editable data to API.

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
  //set gridApi on scope
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
    //Do your REST call here via $hhtp.get or $http.post
    //This alert just shows which info about the edit is available
    alert('Column: ' + colDef.name + ' ID: ' + rowEntity.id + ' Name: ' + rowEntity.name + ' Age: ' + rowEntity.age)
  });
};
```

Comment: You need to have an API that you call that will update the values on the server. Do you have a web API already setup?

Comment: yes I have an API setup in my project. But first I am practicing on plnkr how to do it before implementing to main project.

Comment: It won't be exactly the same. You can use $http.get to read a json file but you won't be able to use $http.post to update the values in plunker I don't think. Example of getting the data from plunker but then it stores it locally and updates just locally the array. https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/724VIV

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar. I use ASP.NET Web API for my back-end. Basically I make a json object, stringify it and pass it along to the post. Then in your web API you update your data store.

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ Key: keyValue, Column: col.field, Value: newValue });

$http.post("api/Account/UpdateData", data)
            .then(function (response) {
            }, function (error, status) {
            });
```

Comment: You can't do a $http.post on plunker so it's a little pointless to edit it on there. You need your own web api that you write to make it work.